# Drupal webform url to edit existing response to field

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I have a webform in Drupal, with 3 questions (fields) (Q1, Q2 and Q3) on 3 different pages.

The users have permission to edit their responses to the webform, and view their own answers.

Hitting on EDIT link now takes the user to the beginning of the form (step 1).

I would like to create 3 links, that would take the user to the respective question, in EDIT mode.

Like:
Link 1 EDIT - Q1(step 1)
Link 2 EDIT - Q2(step 2)
Link 3 EDIT - Q3(step 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to get to a specific page on a multipage webform when editing. The user must start at page 1. See the following link for current discussion about this issue.

http://drupal.org/node/1413250

A way to work around this issue is to create the form on one page, and then use jquery to create a workflow within the page(show/hide fields based on current step) within the form template file of the current node.

You could then use the url querystring or hash to determine which step you are on.

Comment: thanks man :), I also know about the multistep module (http://drupal.org/project/multistep), however the issue with it is the user needs to create a node with it first to make the subsequent steps accessible, any idea if the admin can pre create the node for the user, in order to make the step accessible and editable for the user on first view